# Javascriptの配列の値がif構文でTrueにならない

Tags: javascript, array

Javascriptを始めたばかりで初心者の質問になりますが、ご指導をお願いします。
csvデータ取得　⇒　配列化　⇒　if構文でAの列だけのデータ取得⇒棒グラフにする

上記予定なのですが、for構文の配列上のA,C,A,Bの値は、document.writeで取得できますが、if構文の中の文字列"A"とTrueになりません。なぜでしょうか？すいませんがよろしくお願いします。

csv data は、以下の通りです。
fukuoka,9147,A
nagoya,13047,C
osaka,16920,A
tokyo,23667,B

```
// 2) CSVから２次元配列に変換
function csv2Array(str) {
  var csvData = [];
  var lines = str.split("\n");
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
    var cells = lines[i].split(",");
    csvData.push(cells);
  }
  return csvData;
}

function drawBarChart(data) {
  // 3)chart.jsのdataset用の配列を用意
  var tmpLabels = [], tmpData1 = [];
  for (var row in data) {

      document.write(data[row][2]+": OK! </br>");
      if(data[row][2] === "A" ){
                        document.write("Matchしました");

      }
}

function main() {
  // 1) ajaxでCSVファイルをロード
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var filePath = 'data4.csv';
  req.open("GET", filePath, true);
  req.onload = function() {
    // 2) CSVデータ変換の呼び出し
    data = csv2Array(req.responseText);
    // 3) chart.jsデータ準備、4) chart.js描画の呼び出し
    drawBarChart(data);
  }
  req.send(null);
}

main();
```

Comment: あなたのコードを試してみましたが、`if`文の部分はコードから期待される通りに動作しました。(`drawBarChart`内で`}`が足りない部分については補いました。)あなたは現在のコードでどのような結果になることを期待しているのでしょうか? また、実際にはどのような結果になってしまったのでしょうか? そこら辺のことを具体的に記述してください。現在の「if構文の中の文字列"A"とTrueになりません。」と言う記述では、そこら辺のことがまったくわかりません。

Comment: なお、1つ目の`document.write`のところを`document.write(JSON.stringify(data[row][2])+": OK! </br>");`と書き換えてみるとどうなりますか?

Comment: OOPer様、コメントありがとうございます。
頂いた内容の実行結果は、以下のようになります。
"A\r": OK!
"C\r": OK!
"A\r": OK!
"B": OK!

私のイメージと実際は以下の通りです。
【予想していた内容】data[row][2]がAであるときだけ、「Matchしました」が表示。
【現在実施の内容】data[row][2]がAであっても、何も表示されない。

Comment: CSVファイルの改行コードが `\r\n` である事が原因の様です。`csv2Array()` 関数内で `var lines = str.split("\n");` としている部分を `var lines = str.split("\r\n");` に変更するとどうなるでしょうか。

Comment: 答えは、CSVファイルの改行コードが \r\n である事が原因でした。皆様、貴重なお時間ありがとうございました！